# iOS 12 does not support offline feature of some PWAs

Tags: ios, safari, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

iOS 12 Safari does not support the offline feature of some PWAs (Progressive Web App). It seems like Safari does not cache resources in those web apps properly.

For example, the following PWAs cannot work offline in iOS 12 and 12.1, but they all work perfectly in Chrome on Android or Windows:

The Air Horner PWA that is used by google to demonstrate Service Worker:
[Air Horner](https://airhorner.com)

And these two:
[2048 puzzle](https://2048-opera-pwa.surge.sh)
[Voice Memos](https://voice-memos.appspot.com)

Steps to reproduce (100% reproducible):

1. visit the PWA with Safari (iOS 12 or 12.1)
2. close the PWA tab in Safari
3. push home button on iPhone to set Safari to background
4. push the iPhone power button to turn off screen
5. push the iPhone power button again to wake up the phone
6. turn off all the network connection from the iPhone control center (both wifi and cellular)
7. open Safari, visit PWA again --> the web app fail to load

This has been bothering me for a long time, as my own web app also has the similar issue - works fine in Chrome on Android / Windows but only fails on iOS 12 Safari. Any idea what special in iOS 12 Safari? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved in iOS 12.1.2 on my iPhone 6S.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, using service worker without Workbox resolved the problem - app starts without internet connection but something is messed up with caching - it's not working.

Comment: My app does not use Workbox either. Still not working. The thing is that few offline apps did work, for example, https://simpleoffline.website/ and https://www.currency-calc.com, weird.

Comment: Share just the crucial code on jsfiddle, I will look to it.

Comment: Just take the [airhorner](https://airhorner.com) as example. Its Service Worker script is here (simple enough): https://airhorner.com/sw.js. If I follow the steps list in my question above, the app won't load offline. And it does not use Workbox.

Comment: I've repeated scenario and ended up with the same result. I've asked in comments about this issue https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190269.

Strange is that when you add it to the home screen, run it and then turn off internet connection you can still use it as standalone app - I think the webview treat webapp as a normal cached website. Thats why there are only assets/files downloaded from your visit, there are no assets/files which should be downloaded by service worker - you can test it offline.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issues.

What I realized is, all the caches are set correctly when the service worker is activated, but if you close safari with the iOS task manager (not only reduce it), all cached files get completely deleted when going back on the PWA.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed offline works in the Homescreen. However, the cache does not get updated on new versions & the Homescreen link stops working. To refresh the cache, one is obliged to access the web app from Safari, and then it works again. This is really sub-optimal & will hopefully be fixed.